# How to inflate xml like row

Tags: android, xml

[image: dynamic_layout.xml]

How do I inflate this XML and display like attached image without using ListView and GetView adapter?

Comment: can't see your XML!! EDIT: now it's ok

Comment: What's wrong with using `ListView`? Do you know how many items you'll have in there?

Comment: when i add xml then error give liek add more details every time ..

Comment: multiple row will comes some time 2 row or some 4-5.

Comment: If you don't have fix no of row then use `ListView`

Comment: so you want to create a listview but without using a listview?? why not use what you are suppose to and post what problem you are having

Comment: no i dont want to give look and feel like listview

Comment: please vote actually display -3

Comment: You can give a ListView whatever look and feel you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create you layout like so

```
<ScrollView
<!-- scroll view settings-->
...>
   <LinearLayout 
     android:id="@id/your_layout";
     android:layout_height="wrap_content";
     android:layout_width="match_parent";
     android:orientation="vertical"; >

     <!-- Here you put the TextView about Title, Price, Description(and whatever you need) 
          as often as you want-->

     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But this isn't the best (and not recommended) way ... you should use `ListView` and the `Adapter` for better performance

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a ListView (I don't know why, btw..) the simplest way is to use a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView.

Please note that in this way you're going to lose some useful methods like the setOnItemClickListener, and you have handle this logic manually.

If you actually know which and how many items you have, you can do it; otherwise use what is supposed to be used (or learn how to use it).

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate it with two simple TableLayout xml files..
First define a xml with TableLayout without TableRows, then define another xml with TableLayout with Tile/Price/Description. 
In your code you can use LayoutInflater to inflate as many identical items as you like.
Check out the populateView() method [here](https://github.com/flamearrow/androidTetris/blob/master/AndroidTetris/src/com/ml/gb/tetris/activities/HighScoreListActivity.java).

Where the _scoreListLayout is a [xml](https://github.com/flamearrow/androidTetris/blob/master/AndroidTetris/res/layout/high_score_list.xml) with a row predefined, and newRow 
is another [xml](https://github.com/flamearrow/androidTetris/blob/master/AndroidTetris/res/layout/new_high_score_entry.xml) predefined and can be added arbitrary times to _scoreListLayout according to # of high score items.